# Not Allowing Multiple Button Presses

Tags: java, android

I'm building a camera app with Camera2 API, relatively new to Android development. Everything is working just working out the bugs. But I have a switch camera button, going from the front camera to the back or vise-versa. If the user continuosly presses the button, the app will crash. Trying to set it up in a way that it finishes everything it needs to do before the button can be used again.

I have the button set to enabled, but after press, it disables the button until everyting finishes, then renables, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
//The button to switch the camera to front and back camera.
    mChangeCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
    mChangeCamera.setEnabled(true);
    mChangeCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        mChangeCamera.setEnabled(false);
            closeCamera();
            //  stopBackgroundthread();
            if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
                setUpCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                transformImage(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                connectCamera();

            } else {
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
            }

            mChangeCamera.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

there has to be a simple way to do this, but not finding anyting from searchs. Anyone know how I can set it up not to crash when the user smashes the button?

Comment: Do a search for `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and `SwingWorker`s.

Comment: Ended up getting it with a handler that delays enabling the button again after 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

i did this by calculate time between multiple button presses...
create global variable in your class first

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
```

and a final int for duration between clicks

```
 public static final int CLICK_TIME = 400;
```

then paste this code in on click of button

```
if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < CLICK_TIME) {
      return;  //button pressed repeatedly so do nothing
}
mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

       // button is not pressed repeatedly so add your desired action
```

and of course you can increase the CLICK_TIME value if error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Alight, so I ended up figuring out how to do this. You can use a handler with a post delay like so:

```
 mChangeCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
    mChangeCamera.setEnabled(true);
    mChangeCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mChangeCamera.setEnabled(false);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mChangeCamera.setEnabled(true);
                }
            },1000);
            closeCamera();
            //  stopBackgroundthread();
            if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
                setUpCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                transformImage(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                connectCamera();

            } else {
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
            }


        }
    });
```